# PHP between 2 Date

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i trying to select result date from mysql

mytable:

> id_room | check_in   | check_out

The problem is when i want to check reserved data betwwan date 1 to date 2.

for example my room data:

> **id_room** : *1* ; **check_in** : *2014/11/01* ; **check_out** : *2014/11/08*

So i want to check my booking in, 2014/11/03 and 2014/11/04. In system its will be not resulted thats mean no booking in that date, but in actual life 2014/11/03 and 2014/11/04 must have been booked. Because im check_in in 2014/11/01 and check_out in 2014/11/08.

I'm using

`SELECT * FROM tabel WHERE cek_in BETWEEN  '2014/11/03' AND '2014/11/04' OR  cek_out BETWEEN 2014/11/03' AND '2014/11/04'`

So if there any clue or other logic, please  please tell me :D
Thanks

Comment: Are the `check_in` and `check_out` columns actual date columns, or are they just storing strings? Also I'm sorry but I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: @Andrew , i want create script to check booking date between date1 and date2. Customer can check empty room by searching time period

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly; this is a classic problem you want to include bookings that overlap the dates:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table1
 WHERE cek_out >= '2014-11-03' /* Check OUT >= START of range to check */
   AND cek_in  <= '2014-11-05' /* Check IN  <=  END  of range to check */;
```

UPDATE

So you are running the query above and the room has an existing booking

```
cek_in  = '2014-11-01' (<= '2014-11-05') /* OK */
cek_out = '2014-11-05' (>= '2014-11-03') /* OK */
```

This should show up, are you sure you wrote the correct query? See comments.

Comment: thx for the solution. Im trying to add your sql, but when i check for date '2014-11-03' and '2014-11-05', MySQL gives empty result. In actually, Room1 has already booked for date 01 to date 05. Im so sorry for bad description